# How to change background and foreground color of PNG image to selected from color pallet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, png

I wanted to change the background and foreground color of PNG image. According to selection from color palette.
 I did only on changing color of div or text. But i am blank for PNG image.
And i am posting question first time so 
I am facing problem for posting code
That i did for div and text.

But how do I do it for a PNG image.

**image is PNG base64 format**
I want to change background and foreground with different colors

Comment: A PNG is a rasterized image and you would have to do some processing on the server-side to create a new image. You can only do this client-side with a vector image like a SVG.

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @zgood your comment looks like the correct answer to me. I would have upvoted it!

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to give the PNG a transparent background, and then use Javascript to change the colour of the DOM behind it?
Otherwise could you have multiple PNGs with the different colours and just switch between them?

Otherwise, it can be tricky but you might be able to pull off something like it using canvas or SVGs.

Comment: The OP says _"change the background and foreground"_. your trick doesn't address the foreground color.

Comment: Hence suggestion 2. :)